# AngularJS dynamically call function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

at this point, I'm new to AngularJS.

This works:

```
scope.$apply(scope.hideTooltip());
```

But calling the function dynamically does not work:

```
scope.$apply(
  scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter, {'event': event})
);
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value" ng-enter="hideToolTip()" />
```

The enitre directive:

```
   app.directive('ngEnter', function() {
            return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log(scope.hideTooltip());
                element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
                    if(event.which === 13) {
                        console.log(attrs.ngEnter);
                        scope.$apply(
                            scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter, {'event': event})
                        );
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            };
        });
```

So, how do I call a function dynamically in an AngularJS directive?

Comment: I think what you want to do can be done with isolate scope: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-expression-binding

Comment: you can use `ng-model-options` if you are using angular 1.3 here is the link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like you have missed the argument for the controller method in the HTML

```
// you have missed the event parameter.

<input type="text" ng-model="value" ng-enter="hideToolTip(event)" />

app.directive('ngEnter', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {

      element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
        if (event.which === 13) {

          console.log(attrs.ngEnter);
          scope.$apply(
            scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter, {
              'event': event
            })
          );
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    };
  });
```

in controller

```
 $scope.hideToolTip = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
```

here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/jJA1Lbssh7IMIlaIthUp?p=preview)

P.S. this will call the controller function twice after hitting *ENTER* since your binding both `keydown` and `keypress`events.

**AND Don't forget to remove** the `console.log(scope.hideTooltip());` line.

Comment: That's it. Thanks! Yes, I was passing the event parameter but the controller function didn't have any parameters. Strange that it didn't trigger a method undefined exception.

Comment: :) glad to help you and additionally if you want to call the `console.log(scope.hideTooltip());` the way you have to use here is `console.log(scope.hideToolTip);`, cheerz :)